# Converting large strings to UTF-8

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, utf-8

I have a WCF4 REST service which queries a database and returns JSON.  Some users want to make extremely large queries though I'm having difficulty returning the string.  For example, I need to return a 500M JSON string (all data is ASCII text), though when I try to convert the string from .NET's native UTF-16 I hit an OutOfMemoryException.  Here's a compact sample of what I'm doing.

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/RunQuery", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Stream RunQuery() {
    // Perform query and return serialized json string (~500 million ASCII characters)
    string json = DoQuery(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form);
    // Set output charset
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    // Convert UTF-16 string to UTF-8 (OutOfMemoryException)
    byte jsonBytes[] = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)
    // Send UTF-8 string, without BOM
    return new MemoryStream(jsonBytes);
}
```

It only works if I keep the JSON below 200M or so.  While it runs I see the IIS process' memory usage creep up, and then explode to 2.8G at which point it dies.  The stacktrace reports it occurs at System.String.ToCharArray. I've tried variations of chunking the string to build the byte array but nothing seems to work.  Any idea how I can send this data out without blowing up?

Comment: 500M JSON? Ouch. Can't you split the data into pages instead?

Comment: Just a guess: Can you try writing the response data to a temporary file in chunks, and then return an open stream for the temporary file? (Preferrably you should restructure DoQuery() so it supports writing its result to an output Stream instead of returning a Stream. You really shouldn't buffer whole megabytes of data if you don't have to.)

Comment: Or stream your data back to the client....

Comment: (Now I wonder if there's a way to make WCF services that would let you directly pass an output stream to your code, instead of having to return an input stream to your response.)

Comment: @Polity, can you point to the APIs that do that?

Comment: 500 MB Json is really huge both for server and client. I would try to send the result in chunks(http supports this) while each chunk containing a valid json. Similar to twitters stream API (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by writing your own [stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) implementation that converts the input to utf8 on the fly.

You should be able to do so by extracting portions of the input string, converting them to utf 8 block by block.

Keep in mind that the number of bytes is not neccesarily identical to the character count, unless you never send international characters of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to return stream - use file stream or at least pre-allocate MemoryStream space.

If you have to stick with 500Mb strings:

- use 64bit machine and 64bit process. It is unlikely for x86 process to be able successfully allocate 2 pieces of memory of that size. Note that even if you do use 64 bit process, CLR has restriction on "single block allocation" size of about 2Gb making 1Gb strings unlikely to fit in memory. So at some point near 500Mb - 1Gb switching to 64 bit will no longer help.
- use Writers - they can easily (i.e. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3aadshsx.aspx) encode directly to the output while writing your JSON to it. As additional recommendation - don't even create JSON string to start with, write output to Writer instead.
- If you know that your string is ASCII only - cheat by writing to stream yourself casting each character as byte.

Comment: Unfortunately my service must be 32-bit in order to use the Oracle odp.net driver (Oracle.DataAccess.dll) which doesn't seem to have a 64-bit flavor.

When I make a "new MemoryStream(500000000)" it dies, probably because I have a 500000000 character string sitting in memory.  That does bypass the whole byte array though, which helps.  The JSON is generated by JavaScriptSerializer which gives me a choice of a String or StringBuilder as output.  I wish I could simply return my serialized object but it uses nested Dictionaries...

Comment: I see - you have to be insanely careful with large results in 32 bit processes, i.e. 2 such request at the same time will kill your server anyway. Consider using json.net serializer (json.codeplex.com) as it gives you more flexibility than built in one like - http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm. Otherwise the only option I see is to write your own JSON serialization and write directly to response stream...